# $A$ is a $n \times n$ matrix over $\mathbb{R}$ such that $A^2+A+5I=0$. Find the characteristic polynomial of the matrix $A$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

$A$ is a $n \times n$ matrix over $\mathbb{R}$ such that $A^2+A+5I=0$.
Find the characteristic polynomial of the matrix $A$.

it is a question from a test i had yesterday and this is how it was written. 
if it is vague to you, you might not be too familiar with this domain.

good luck and thanks for your support (:

Comment: Zeros of the characteristic polynomial $p(x)$ are among $q(x)=x^2+x+5$ which are complex. Thus $n$ is even and $p(x)=q(x)^{n/2}$.

Comment: That's false, since $A$ also satisfies $3 q$: your claim would then say that $p(x) = (3 q(x))^{n/2}$, and these can't both be true. I think you need a constant.

Comment: @JohnHughes The characteristic polynomial of a matrix is usually defined to be monic. Even if the alternative definition is used, where the leading coefficient is taken as $(-1)^n$ the fact that $n$ is even would give leading coefficient $1$.

Comment: Good point, Mark.

Comment: ..but if the given polynomial were, say, $2A^2 + A + 5I = 0$, then you'd need to make it monic before raising it to the $n/2$ power, which might not be obvious to OP.

Comment: thank you very much!! i read all of your comments and I finally got it!
thank you for your help and support (:

Answer (score 4):

As $\;p(x)=x^2+x+5\;$  has two conjugate complex roots, and $A\in \mathcal M_n(\mathbf R)$, it is the *minimal polynomial*  of $A$. Now $\;\chi_A(x)$, the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is a multiple of $p(x)$, and it has the same (complex) roots. As $\;\chi_A(x)\in\mathbf R[x]$, the two conjugate roots have the same multiplicity, hence $\chi_A(x)$ is a power of $p(x)$. As $\deg \chi_A(x)=n$, this can happen only if $n$ is even, and in such a case:
$$\chi_A(x)=(x^2+x+5)^{n/2}.$$

Comment: thank you very much!! i read all of your comments and I finally got it!
thank you for your help and support (:

Comment: very nice answer!

Answer (score 3):

1. If a matrix $B$ satisfies a polynomial $q$, i.e., if $q(B) = 0$, then every eigenvalue of $B$ satisfies $q$ as well. (I'll prove that for you at the bottom.)
2. In this problem, $A$ is not the identity or a multiple of it, because no real multiple of $I$ satisfies the given polynomial $p$.

$$
\newcommand{\ubar}{\bar{u}}
$$

3. $p$ has two roots; call them $u$ and $\ubar$. They're complex conjugates. Every eigenvalue of $A$ is therefore (by claim 1) either $u$ or $\ubar$. These evalues appear in conjugate pairs (because $A$ is real), so the evalues of $A$ look like 
   $$
   u, \ubar;u, \ubar;\ldots ; u, \ubar.
   $$
   (Note that this means that there are an even number of roots, so $n$ is even.)
4. Thus the polynomial for $A$ is an $n$th degree polynomial  with these roots.
   That means that it looks like $C((x-u)(x-\ubar))^\frac{n}{2}$. Since $(x-u)(x-\ubar)$ is just $p$, the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is
   $$
   C p(x)^\frac{n}{2}.
   $$
5. And since the characteristic polynomial for even $n$ always has leading coefficient $1$, in this case we know that $C = 1$.

Proof of claim 1: 
Suppose that $c$ is an eigenvalue of $B$ and $v$ is a corresponding (possibly complex) eigenvector. Then look at

\begin{align}
p(B)v 
&= (a_n B^n + a_{n-1}B^{n-1} + \ldots + a_0 I)v\\
&= a_n B^n v + a_{n-1}B^{n-1} v + \ldots + a_0 I v\\
&= a_n c^n v + a_{n-1}c^{n-1} v + \ldots + a_0  v\\
&= (a_n c^n  + a_{n-1}c^{n-1}  + \ldots + a_0)  v
\end{align}
Now since $p(B)$ is the zero matrix, we know that $p(B)v = 0$. So this tells is that 
\begin{align}
0 &= (a_n c^n  + a_{n-1}c^{n-1}  + \ldots + a_0)  v
0 &= p(c)  v
\end{align}
Since $v$ is an eigenvector, it's nonzero, so $p(c)$ must be $0$.

Comment: thank you very much!! i read all of your comments and I finally got it!
thank you for your help and support (:

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be found using Caley-Hamilton Theorem. 
It will be $\lambda^2 + \lambda + 5 = 0$. Here eigen roots will be complex.

Comment: The degree of the characteristic polynomial is $n$, but it'll have the same roots (with different multiplicity) as $X^2+X+5$.

Comment: so may i write that that charctaristic polynomial is $(λ^2+λ+5)^(n/2) $ ?

Comment: Misuse of Cayley-Hamilton Theorem here. You first have to show some preliminary results before using [it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem).

Comment: @Koushik take the matrix $\lambda I$ it satisfies $A-\lambda I=0$ but that is not the characteristic polynomial but actually it is the minimal polynomial

Comment: i am really confused over here... can someone please be more specific?

Comment: thank you very much!! i read all of your comments and I finally got it!
thank you for your help and support (: