# Let $A \in M_n(\mathbb R)$ such that $A^2+A+5I_n = 0$. Find the characteristic polynomial of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, characteristic-polynomial, cayley-hamilton

> Let $A \in M_n(\mathbb R)$ such that $$A^2+A+5I_n = 0$$ Find the characteristic polynomial of $A$.

I tried two different approaches and got stuck on both. I am wondering if I was even headed in the right direction.

---

**First attempt:**

Let $g(x) = x^2+x+5$. Using the datum we have $g(A) = 0$, thus implying through Cayley Hamilton theorem that $g(x) \setminus f_A(x)$.

Therefore we have, $f_A(x) = (x^2+x+5)h(x)$,

where $h(x)$ is some monic polynomial s.t deg($h$) = $n-2$.

This being the point I got stuck.

---

**Second attempt:**

By datum $A^2+A+5I=0 \implies A = -(A^2+5I) \implies f_A=f_{-(A^2+5I)}$

Therefore we have $f_A = det(xI+A^2+5I) = det((x+5)I+A^2)$.

This being the point I got stuck again unfortunately.

---

Hoping to get some direction and tips about what I've got and what I need.

Comment: [$A$ is a $n \times n$ matrix over $\mathbb{R}$ such that $A^2+A+5I=0$. Find the characteristic polynomial of the matrix $A$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1382934/a-is-a-n-times-n-matrix-over-mathbbr-such-that-a2a5i-0-find-the) is a duplicate question. Also see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3684363/finding-characteristic-polynomial?noredirect=1). Basically, you wrote that $f_A(x) = (x^2+x+5)h(x)$ above, but more is true : $x^2+x+5$ is the minimal polynomial of $A$, so the roots of $h$ are the same as the roots of $g$. Thus, $h$ is an appropriate power of $g$.